# Does Log-Lipschitz regularity imply Hölder continuity?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A function is Log-Lipschitz if there exists a constant $C$ such that
\begin{equation}
|u(x) - u(y)| \le C|x-y| \log|x-y|
\end{equation}
Is a Log-Lipschitz function $C^{0,\alpha}$ for any $\alpha \in (0,1)
$(Hölder continuous)?
If you need, assume hypothesis. Thank you.

Comment: $\log|x-y|$ is negative for $|x-y|<1$. Doesn't that cause a problem?

Comment: Dejan, No, because we can assume a C<0 such that satisfy this condition, yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is -- assuming that you think and act locally. Think in terms of moduli of continuity $\omega$, i.e., functions such that $|u(x)-u(y)|\le \omega(|x-y|)$. The function $\delta\log (1/\delta)$ is smaller than $\delta^{\alpha}$ ($\alpha<1$) near $0$.

Edit: For $|x-y| < 1$ it is clear that $\log|x-y| < 0$. Commonly this is fixed by adding the modulus: $|\log |x-y||$. In the notation of moduli of continuity the issue is resolved by writing $\log(1/\delta) = - \log(\delta)$, where $\delta$ is small.

Comment: By "locally", do you by any chance mean something like: $u:D\to\Bbb R^n$ is log-Lipschitz if for each $x\in D$ there exist a constant $C\in\Bbb R$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that for all $y\in U$ the inequality $|u(x) - u(y)| \le C|x-y| \log|x-y|$ holds?

Comment: @DejanGovc Not really: I just meant that Holder continuity is usually considered for not-too-large distances, say $|x-y|<1$. Otherwise we'd have to say that $f(x)=x$ is not Holder continuous on $\mathbb R$ with exponents $\alpha<1$.

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify some things.

Comment: Thank you but, insted $\delta \log(1/\delta) $ should not be $\delta \log(\delta) $?

Comment: @Marcos As other people already pointed out, logarithm is negative for small values of its argument. Do you see why this is a problem for the inequality that you stated?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not answering the question, just pointing out that that $\log|x-y|$ should be replaced by $|\log|x-y||$, otherwise the function $u$ is just a constant unless of course $C<0$!