# Is this true that, $u \in \bigcap_{ \alpha<1} C^{0, \alpha}$ implies $u \in C^{0,1}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is there a holder continuous function with any order less than 1, but not Lipschitz. Or does $u \in \bigcap_{\alpha<1} C^{0, \alpha}$ imply $u \in C^{0,1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a log-Lipschitz function, i.e. one that satisfies
$$ |u(x) - u(y)| \le C|x-y| |\log|x-y||$$
 is $C^{0,\alpha}$ for any $\alpha<1$, but not Lipschitz. See this [MSE post.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158888/does-log-lipschitz-regularity-imply-h%C3%B6lder-continuity) An example of such a function is

$$|x||\log|x||$$

Comment: What is in your brain???